# The value of $a$ that maximizes $g(a)?$

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a normal random variable with mean $2$ and variance $4$ and $g(a)=P(a \leq X \leq a+2)$. The value of $a$ that maximizes $g(a)?$

My thought: From the given information about random variable we get a standard normal. But after that how do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** We have that

$$\mathbb P(a \leq X \leq a+2)=\int_a^{a+2}\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi}}\,e^{-(x-2)^2/8}\,dx$$

Comment: @ramram ... and differentiate on $a$...

Comment: Yes, I got it , The value of $a$ is one...thanks

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help.

Comment: I should note that another way to go about it would be to note that the usual 'bell curve' of the standard normal distribution is now symmetric about $x=2$, rather than $x=0$. It's no coincidence that you found $a=1$: if $I$ is some interval of fixed length, $\mathbb P (X\in I)$ is maximized when $I$'s midpoint is at $x=2$, the peak of the 'bell curve' for $X$.

Comment: This last comment of yours is a much better answer than your post... :-)

Comment: @Did Thank you; perhaps I should indeed have posted that as an answer. The downside is that it is very specific to normal distributions, while the current answer works in more general settings.